# all.equal on object with NULL names causes 'Error: not compatible with STRSXP' -- bug or expected?

Tags: r, dplyr

In the example below, when names are set to `NULL`, `all.equal` throws `'Error: not compatible with STRSXP'`
However, if names are set to `NA` (or some other value), `all.equal` works as normal.
**Is this expected behavior or a bug?**

```
## SAMPLE DATA
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(LETTERS[1:3], rnorm(3))
names(x) <- NULL

x
#   NA        NA
# 1  A -0.626454
# 2  B  0.183643
# 3  C -0.835629

all.equal(x, x)
# Error: not compatible with STRSXP

# add names back in, even 'NA'
names(x) <- c(NA, NA)
all.equal(x, x)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I bet you have **dplyr** loaded! I think it's a bug in the `all.equal.data.frame` method from that package, which is being dispatched instead.

Comment: Be sure to start R with no additional packages, R --vanilla or similar; report your R version. This is not seen for me under a `> R.version.string` [1] "R Under development (unstable) (2014-01-22 r64855)" or "R version 3.0.2 Patched (2014-01-02 r64626)"

Comment: @joran, I do indeed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Replacing `all.equal` with `all.equal.default` resolved it.

Comment: BTW crashing R and totally unhelpful error messages are __definitely__ bugs

Comment: Please don't make up tags like `all.equal`. I mean what general value would that tag have...

Comment: @NiklasB., sure, but I am curious what sort of drawbacks doing so would have?

Comment: I got this error when I tried foolishly to left_join three data frames.  A human error, but unhelpful error message.

Answer (score 10):

As @Joran points out, this seems to be related to `dplyr`. 
Filed as an issue: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/219

Temporary work around (for my need at least. Will not work for all) is to use

```
 all.equal.default(x, x)
```

FYI:

```
  ## STARTING FROM A FRESH SESSION:

  set.seed(1)
  x <- data.frame(LETTERS[1:3], rnorm(3))
  names(x) <- NULL

  all.equal(x, x)
  # [1] TRUE

  ## Load in dplyr
  library(dplyr)
  all.equal(x, x)
  # Error: not compatible with STRSXP
```