# Apply functions using data from two different lists of data frames

Tags: r, lapply, mapply

I am looking to use data from a list of related data frames in calculations done on another list of data frames.

Currently, my code is like this:

```
library(dplyr)

#Set up Dummy Data
types = c("A", "B", "C")
value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
value3 = c(100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350)
df_1 = data.frame(types, value, value3)

value2 = c(.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6)
value4 = c(.01, .02, .03, .04, .04, .06)
df_2 = data.frame(types, value2, value4)

#Split into lists
split1 = split(df_1, df_1$types)
split2 = split(df_2, df_2$types)

#run function inside of one list within each data frame.
split1 = lapply(split1, function(x) mutate(x, multiply = value * value3))
#run function inside of one list using data from corresponding data in different list
test = lapply(split2, function(x) select(x, value2))
lapply(split1, function(x) mutate(x, divide = value3/test))
```

The final line of code generates the error "non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Comment: It seems you use a separate package for the function named `mutate`

Comment: With `lapply(split1, function(x) mutate(x, divide = value3/test))`, `test` is a list of data frames, so you are trying to divide a numeric vector by a list of dataframes.

Comment: I have edited the original question to load `dplyr` library and added `lapply` and `mapply` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit unclear, but you seem to want to join two sets of data on the common column `type` and do operations using values from both sets. Since you already seem to be using the dplyr package, let's use that to join the two data frames and then create new columns (column names are `multiply` and `divide`) using `mutate()`:

```
library(dplyr)    
df_1 %>% left_join(df_2, by = 'types') %>% mutate(multiply = value * value3, 
                                                        divide = value3/value2)
```

Output:

```
   types value value3 value2 value4 multiply    divide
1      A     1    100    0.1   0.01      100 1000.0000
2      A     1    100    0.4   0.04      100  250.0000
3      B     2    150    0.2   0.02      300  750.0000
4      B     2    150    0.5   0.04      300  300.0000
5      C     3    200    0.3   0.03      600  666.6667
6      C     3    200    0.6   0.06      600  333.3333
7      A     4    250    0.1   0.01     1000 2500.0000
8      A     4    250    0.4   0.04     1000  625.0000
9      B     5    300    0.2   0.02     1500 1500.0000
10     B     5    300    0.5   0.04     1500  600.0000
11     C     6    350    0.3   0.03     2100 1166.6667
12     C     6    350    0.6   0.06     2100  583.3333
```

Comment: I will explore this further.  I was wanting to try and keep each of the types in their own data frame as there are a series of functions that are already applied to individual data frames that I wanted to use without much modification.  If I must modify though, I will.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks -- in the future, giving an example of desired output would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a desired output, its hard to tell what you want exactly, but from looking at your code it seems like you want another variable onto each of the dataframes in your list. To do this you just need to modify your current code slightly. Simply change the last line to:

```
res<-lapply(seq_along(split1), function(y, n, i) { 
                          mutate(y[[i]], divide = value3/as.data.frame(test[n[i]])) }, y=split1, n=names(split1)
             )
```

What we are doing here is passing indexes to the `lapply` function and then we are also passing your `split1` object and the `names(split1)` as parameters into the function. That way we can access them the way we want. The result is:

```
 res
[[1]]
  types value value3 multiply value2
1     A     1    100      100   1000
4     A     4    250     1000    625

[[2]]
  types value value3 multiply value2
2     B     2    150      300    750
5     B     5    300     1500    600

[[3]]
  types value value3 multiply   value2
3     C     3    200      600 666.6667
6     C     6    350     2100 583.3333
```

Two things to note: (1) The names aren't the same, I have yet to figure out how to do this using `lapply` but it can easily be done after the fact with:

`names(res) <- names(split1)`

and (2) It looks like the new variable is called `value2` however it is actually `divide` like we specified in our `mutate`. This is seen by:

```
 names(res[[1]])
[1] "types"    "value"    "value3"   "multiply" "divide"
```

This looks like a display issue, almost like variable labels vs. variable names, and I dont know how to fix it immediately, but you can still access the values through something like:

```
 res[[1]]["divide"]
  value2
1   1000
4    625
```

Comment: That is the type of output I was looking for.  When I try your code I get the error "not compatible with STRSXP".

Comment: I think this is a known issue with `dplyr` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391113/all-equal-on-object-with-null-names-causes-error-not-compatible-with-strsxp) have you attached it? If you have try starting new R session or detaching it with something like `detach("package:dplyr", unload=TRUE)`

Comment: I tried both restarting and detaching, but the error is still generated.

Comment: Hmmm, try this `detach("package:dplyr", unload=TRUE)
detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE)
library(plyr)` - detach both `plyr` and `dplyr` and then load only `plyr`.

Comment: Or you could specify that we want the `plyr` mutate with `plyr::mutate`

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you'd like to accomplish is applying a function on two different lists, first on 1st elements of both, then 2nd elements of both, etc.

This is what `mapply()` does. I have replaced your last line of code with the following code:

```
result = split1

result$divide = mapply(function(x, y) {x$value3 / y$value2}, split1, test)
```

I think you get the idea. You can try using `dplyr` to do the same thing.